# Trouble displaying test results in browser with Mocha, Chai, and webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, testing, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I am using Webdriver.io with Mocha and Chai. I've written several tests that work great from the command line. It opens the Chrome browser, runs the tests, and displays the resultsin the command line. However I am having issues getting the results of the tests to display in the browser view (have a presentation that I would like to show the tests in the browser view). I'm using the mocha html template for viewing tests in the browser, but it only displays "passes: 0failures: 0duration: 0s" in the upper right. I've copied the html file to the first file in my testing structure and changed the paths to the js and css files. I don't see anything in here that references webdriver.io, is that the missing piece?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mocha</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script src="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.setup('bdd');</script>
    <script src="./test/specs/createNewProduct.js"></script>
    <script>
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm opening the file by right clicking on it and opening with Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not clear understand what you want to achieve. But have look to https://github.com/webdriverio-boneyard/wdio-allure-reporter
It is generate beautiful reports for wdio